# Publication Lazarus project in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, application-development, lazarus

Can I publish desktop application has developed in Lazarus IDE in Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/ look there. Should get you started, though this is probably a dupe, as dobey marked.

Answer (score 1):

To have software for the Ubuntu Software Centre you need to package it and then submit it. The packaging is important as the software centre does not compile the source. [Full instructions are here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/).